# How would I check the amount of days between to dates

Tags: p5.js

```
let days
let months
let years

function setup() {
// Our anniversary is 4/7/2019
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  days = day()-7
  months = month()-4
  years = year()

}

function draw() {
  background(255, 0, 150);
  //heart
  strokeWeight(0)
  fill(255, 0, 0)
  ellipse(200, 200, 250, 250)
  ellipse(400, 200, 250, 250)
  triangle(110, 290, 300, 490, 490, 290)
  ellipse(300, 300, 100, 100)
  //text
  fill(0)
  textStyle(BOLD);
  textSize(20)
  textAlign(CENTER, TOP)
  text('It has been ' + months + ' months and ' + days + ' days since \n we first started dating', 300, 250)
}
```

My problem is that after the new year or any month change the dates will go into the negatives.
 How would I make it so it keeps track of today's date and the set date and tells me the time in between them?

Comment: How would you figure this out without a computer? If I gave you two dates, how would you calculate how many days were between them?

Comment: Subtraction, but different months have a different amount of days in them. When the date is changed to 2020 or a new month it displays a negative. I don’t know how to keep track of the of the amount of days and months that have passed without it going to a negative or losing all its data in a new year.

Comment: How do you keep track of that stuff when you're doing this by paper? Taking a step back, you need to [break your problem down into smaller steps](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program). Maybe step 1 would be creating a variable that holds how many days are in each month?

Answer (score 0):

I'll point you in the right direction.

JavaScript has a Date object you can use:

```
let anniversary;

function setup() {
  // Our anniversary is 4/7/2019
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  anniversary = new Date(2019, 7, 4); // initialise your anniversary
```

You can also get the current date by simply newing up a `new Date()`

`let currentDate = new Date();`

You could use this to calculate the difference between the two dates, there's endless resources for this. [Here's one to get you going!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: ```let anniversary;

function setup() {
  // Our anniversary is 4/7/2019
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  anniversary = new Date(2019, 7, 4); // initialise your anniversary
}

function draw() {
background(213)
text(anniversary, 10, 10)
}```
It prints the variable but how do I remove the extra junk and extract only the data I want, like the month and make that a variable that way I can turn the data into a sentence.

Comment: Try `anniversary.getMonth()`. check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date for a comprehensive list of all the methods.